# Is it possible to return dynamic array of struct in Go function?

Tags: arrays, go, struct

Apparently, I want to return an array of struct based on the function parameter (**getOccupationStructs function**) in order to keep DRY (not using if else in every other functions), but it seems impossible to do, so here is my errors:

```
 cannot use []Student literal (type []Student) as type []struct {} in
   return argument
 cannot use []Employee literal (type []Employee ) as type []struct {} in
   return argument
```

and here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
)

type Human struct {
    ID          uint        `gorm:"primary_key" gorm:"column:_id" json:"_id"`
    Name        string      `gorm:"column:name" json:"name"`
    Age         int         `gorm:"column:age" json:"age"`
    Phone       string      `gorm:"column:phone" json:"phone"`
}

type Student struct {
    Human 
    School      string      `gorm:"column:school" json:"school"`
    Loan        float32     `gorm:"column:loan" json:"loan"`
}

type Employee struct {
    Human 
    Company     string      `gorm:"column:company" json:"company"`
    Money       float32     `gorm:"column:money" json:"money"`
}

func getOccupationStructs(occupation string) []struct{} {
    switch occupation {
        case "student":
            return []main.Student{}
        case "employee":
            return []main.Employee{}
        default:
            return []main.Student{}
    }
}

func firstFunction(){
    m := getOccupationStructs("student")
    for _, value := range m{
        fmt.Println("Hi, my name is "+value.Name+" and my school is "+value.School)
    }
}

func secondFunction(){
    m := getOccupationStructs("employee")
    for _, value := range m{
        fmt.Println("Hi, my name is "+value.Name+" and my company is "+value.Company)
    }
}
```

Is there any valid workaround to cope this problem?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @Nadh I've already added it to the question, thanks for reminding me

Comment: As @nothingmuch pointed out in the answer, Go doesn't have structural subtyping. It doesn't have generics either. So, either you can try achieving this by implementing an interface, or implementing `getStudentStructs()`, `getEmployeeStructs()` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go doesn't have structural subtyping, so to get polymorphism you'll need to use an interface.

Define an interface that all struct types implement, it can even be private, like `interface embedsHuman { Name() string }`, and then return `[]embedsHuman`.

Alternatively, restructure your schema or only the Go representation of it as something less hierarchical (perhaps humans can have many roles?), so that it doesn't clash with Go's type system.